# How to combine different partitions of an Pyspark RDD through the use of a custom action/function?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, mergesort

I am trying to create a parallel implementation of the merge sort algorithm in Pyspark with python, i am fairly new to the whole parallel processes so I am having a hard time. The idea is to split the array into n partitions and then on each partition preform a separate merge sort to sort the array and eventually merging all the partitions into one fully sorted array.

I managed to sort the partitions with each process separately, thus each partition holds a sorted array but my problem lies with the merging of the sorted arrays back into one large sorted array. I cannot figure out how to do this efficiently.

I succeeded by using collect() or take() and then an for each partition preforming the merge (its a custom function which takes two arrays and merge them into one, if they both are already sorted the result will be sorted as well) as shown below, but when the array becomes enormous the collect() or take() just take forever and therefore this is not a feasible solution

```
result = []
for element in rdd.collect():
    result = merge(result, element)
```

I am guessing I should use something like mapPartitionWithIndex but i cannot get it to work, essentially I am trying to use partition[0] and merge it with partition[1] and so on.

Is there an other way to achieve similar results with much better preformance? since like this the parallel version of the algorithm loses hard to the normal algortihm with just one process, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of how this can be achieved -

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([16,984,4234,65657,343, 11,7,9, 54,2],2)
rdd2 = sc.parallelize([17, 12,8,10],2)
rdd3=rdd1.union(rdd2)
def sortedpartition(iterator):
  return sorted(iterator)
rdd3.mapPartitions(sortedpartition).sortBy(lambda x: x).collect()
```

output =

```
 [2, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 16, 17, 54, 343, 984, 4234, 65657]
```

If you create a custom function that sorts the partition. when you try to join all the partition into final one , the order can not be guaranteed.
for example -

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([16,984,4234,65657,343, 11,7,9, 54,2],2)
rdd2 = sc.parallelize([17, 12,8,10],2)
rdd3=rdd1.union(rdd2)
def sortedpartition(iterator):
  return sorted(iterator)
rdd3.mapPartitions(sortedpartition).collect()
```

output will be

```
[16, 343, 984, 4234, 65657, 2, 7, 9, 11, 54, 12, 17, 8, 10]
```

so you need to have sorting on the final output as well. That's why I added sortBy transformation to take care of the final sorting in parallel.

---

Another theoretical Approach could be to write custom partitionBy function logic to send the array element to appropriate partition in the order of partition number.

for example -

```
if array is  [2,5,3,7,6,17,12,14]
then custom partition function will read element and distribute like below - 
partition1 - 2,7,6,5,7
partition2 - 17,12,14
and then just running custom partition level sort and collect or save will work.
```